# UNITY button onClick not working in mobile but working fine in pc

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made some actions on clicking a button in unity.It is working fine while I am running it in unity simulator,but not working in mobile.I have also given functions to the button while `onClick`.But its not working.

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Comment: If something doesn't work, it helps if you show us the thing which doesn't work. Otherwise all we can say is that the problem is probably because of something in the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have activated the Mobile Input on the toolbar, if yes then look if in your scene have a EventSystem (if not, right click on hierarchy and create one), at least, if the problem continues please show us the code of the function that its called when press the button. we cant solve a problem that cant see.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, none of the solutions solved it. But then I realized, I have an Image next to the Button, and on the mobile, the Image scales up and its raycast target covers the Button, so just turn off the raycast target of that Image or resize it, and problem solved.